# Any EventListener loggging mechanism in Cypress-Cucumber? Like we have EventFiringWebDriver in Selenium or TestNGListeners in TestNG

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am new to Cypress and looking for a library to use in my cypress-cucumber project that provides event based log creation during execution.
We have something similar in Selenium/TestNG called listeners

For instance, a particular method gets called, say `beforeClick()`, before Cypress clicks on any element.

Any help/idea is appreciated; thanks!